# Sharepoint access denied error

Tags: 2013, permissions

We had extended our Existing SP Web Application as below

```
Default :http://mysite.xxx.com
Intranet :https://people.xxx.com
```

After that we are having some strange issues if i go to a Site Collection like http://mysite.xxx.com/sites/hr (Here i am SC admin )i am able to access the site fine but if i go to the same site using the extended URL https://people.xxx.com/sites/hr i am getting an access denied .I had already checked the superuser and super reader accounts and they have been given the correct permissions as per the tech net article and also they are added to all the Zones for the web application .Can someone please suggest me what else am i missing here

**Update 1**
After debugging more i found that i am able to access some of the site collections with extended url .For Eg i am able to access the root site collection of the web application all the time .But if i go to other sites in the Managed path(https://people.xxx.com/sites/hr)i am getting access denied and if i open the same URL with the default zone (http://mysite.xxx.com/sites/hr) its opening fine

Comment: do you have the proper IIS bindings with extended webapp, SSL? what URL u mentioned when run the powershell command for SuperUser and Super reader? http or https?

Comment: I had used the https when setting up the superuser and superreader ,But after setting up in https i had checked the http super user and super reader and it updated those accounts also